# C# Exibir hora em controle textbox

Tags: c#

Preciso mostrar apenas a hora local em um controle `TextBox`.

No seguinte formato:

```
hh:mm:ss
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso em C#?

Comment: Você pode usar o `MaskedTextBox` para esta finalidade.

Answer (score 5):

Uma maneira possível:

## Formato de 12h

```
textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

## Formato de 24h

```
textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um binding pra que o `TextBox` seja constantemente atualizado conforme o tempo passa. A forma mais direta de fazer é diretamente no XAML. Ficaria desse jeito:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='HH:mm:ss ', Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Uma alternativa para a resposta do @rubStackOverflow:

```
DateTime n = DateTime.Now;
TextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", n.Hour, n.Minute, n.Second);
```